# SharePoint calendar linked to dcoument uploads

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Does the SharePoint calendar have the funtionality to link to document uploads? We are using SharePoint to track the annual/semi-annual certification of documents. Ideally, we would like the calendar to be able to pick up when a document was modified and put an event on the calendar for a year or 6 months later. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you both.  Similarly, do SharePoint’s task lists have the capability to display documents that due for certification/modification within a given timeframe?  For example, it would pick up that a document has an annual certification date of 12/31/15 and would display the document 2 months prior as a reminder on 10/31/15.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a direct way to do this.

I would probably work it that so that when an item is created, using a workflow, create an entry in your calendar. I would also include a field in the calendar where you could write the URL of the file so there is a "trackback". Then once it is in the calendar, you can do what ever you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs for the Calendar, you can also just add some additional date/time fields that you require and then create a Calendar view. You could use a calculated column to get the date 6 months out.

There are limitation with calendar views however.  You can't overly them on with calendar lists, and they don't sync up with Outlook.